# Regex in PHP preg_match_all behaves different than regex101.com

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the numbers in an array. This is my string and my code.

```
$split_times = "return escape('<table class=\'split\' ><tr><td class=\'split0\'>50m</td><td class=\'split1\'>28.86</td><td class=\'split2\'>28.86</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>100m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:01.56</td><td class=\'split2\'>32.70</td></tr><tr><td class=\'splitsep\' colspan=\'3\'></td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>150m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:36.88</td><td class=\'split2\'>35.32</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>200m</td><td class=\'split1\'>2:59:09.93</td><td class=\'split2\'>33.05</td></tr></table>')";

preg_match_all("/split1\\\'>(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)</", $split_times, $split_times_distances);
print_r($split_times_distances);
```

It should return an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => split1\'>28.86<
            [1] => split1\'>1:01.56<
            [2] => split1\'>1:36.88<
            [3] => split1\'>2:59:09.93<
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28.86
            [1] => 1:01.56
            [2] => 1:36.88
            [3] => 2:59:09.93
        )

)
```

but instead, it only shows the first index of both arrays.

Comment: try rubular.com

Comment: Parsing html markup with a regular expression.... ouch...

Comment: @clearshot66 Why ruby when using PHP?

Comment: Your returning values which aren't even in the original content?  `class=\'split`\' for example.

Comment: I edited my question, I pasted the wrong strings

Comment: rubular. It's a regex testing site. NOT only ruby. @chris85

Comment: @clearshot66 It denotes itself as a Ruby regex editor... `a Ruby regular expression editor`, maybe ruby uses PCRE, regex101 has support marked for pcre though.

Comment: Well, it's worked for 8 years on php testing so.

Comment: @clearshot66 That would depend on the regex you are running, PCRE verbs won't work there.

Comment: @clearshot66 and chris85 both regex testers say I'm doing the right thing: selecting 50, 100 and 200.

Comment: Possibly the only think worse than trying to parse HTML with a regex ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454 ) is trying to parse HTML embedded in Javascript using a regex.

Comment: @symcbean can you show me a better way of selecting these values in PHP? The problem here is that I already got this from a dom_xpath query since this html string was inside a onmouse attribute of some other html element on the page I was scraping

Comment: @chris85 this `preg_match_all` however, returns two arrays: `array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => ">50m<"
    1 => ">100m<"
    3 => ">200m<"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "50"
    1 => "100"
    3 => "200"
  ]
]` where the second array is the right one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148806/discussion-between-derk-jan-speelman-and-chris85).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was this: simply select all characters between two strings. In this case based on the `<td>` classname.

```
print_r(preg_match_all("/split1\\\'>(.*?)</", $split_times, $split_times_distances));
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => split1\'>28.86<
            [1] => split1\'>1:01.56<
            [2] => split1\'>1:36.88<
            [3] => split1\'>2:59:09.93<
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28.86
            [1] => 1:01.56
            [2] => 1:36.88
            [3] => 2:59:09.93
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match `=\'split1\'>1:36.88<`

You have to add `(?:\d+:){0,2}` at the begining.

```
$split_times = "return escape('<table class=\'split\' ><tr><td class=\'split0\'>50m</td><td class=\'split1\'>28.86</td><td class=\'split2\'>28.86</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>100m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:01.56</td><td class=\'split2\'>32.70</td></tr><tr><td class=\'splitsep\' colspan=\'3\'></td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>150m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:36.88</td><td class=\'split2\'>35.32</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>200m</td><td class=\'split1\'>2:59:09.93</td><td class=\'split2\'>33.05</td></tr></table>')";

preg_match_all("/split1\\\'>((?:\d+:){0,2}\d+(?:\.\d+)?)</", $split_times, $split_times_distances);
//                    here __^^^^^^^^^^^^^
print_r($split_times_distances);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => split1\'>28.86<
            [1] => split1\'>1:01.56<
            [2] => split1\'>1:36.88<
            [3] => split1\'>2:59:09.93<
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28.86
            [1] => 1:01.56
            [2] => 1:36.88
            [3] => 2:59:09.93
        )

)
```

Comment: Will this also match values like "1:59:08.69" ?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman: No, it will not. For such matches you have to change into `(?:\d+:){0,2}`, see my edit

Comment: Id like to select the entire content of the <td> element, no matter what is says.

Comment: Id like so select **all characters** between these two strings: "split0\'>" and "</td>"

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman: Sorry, I don't get you, it's completely different from OP.

Comment: Please note the "2:59:09.93"

Comment: @chris85 I just want to select the value between two strings

Comment: I want to select it by classname like I said in our discussion. I want to select all characters between split0\'> and </td>

Answer (score 1):

You have already extracted your string from an *`onMouse...`* attribute using `DOMDocument`, why not continue?
Without using a dedicated Javascript parser, it's easy to extract Javascript strings, then all you have to do is to remove escaped quotes to obtain the "raw" string:

```
$onMouseAttr = "return escape('<table class=\'split\' ><tr><td class=\'split0\'>50m</td><td class=\'split1\'>28.86</td><td class=\'split2\'>28.86</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>100m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:01.56</td><td class=\'split2\'>32.70</td></tr><tr><td class=\'splitsep\' colspan=\'3\'></td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>150m</td><td class=\'split1\'>1:36.88</td><td class=\'split2\'>35.32</td></tr><tr><td class=\'split0\'>200m</td><td class=\'split1\'>2:59:09.93</td><td class=\'split2\'>33.05</td></tr></table>')";

# first step: extracting the strings

$stringPattern = <<<'EOD'
~ " ( [^"\\]* (?:\\.[^"\\]*)* ) "  |  ' ( [^'\\]* (?:\\.[^'\\]*)* ) ' ~xsS
EOD;

if ( preg_match_all($stringPattern, $onMouseAttr, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        # unescape the string for the correct quote
        $html = isset($match[2]) ? str_replace("\\'", "'", $match[2])
                                 : str_replace('\\"', '"', $match[1]);

        # extract the nodes you want with DOMDocument/DOMXPath
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $nodeList = $xp->query('//td[@class="split1"]');
        foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
            # display them
            echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
            # or store them
            # $results[] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a solid way to do this indeed. What I came up with eventually was this: `preg_match_all("/split0\\\'>(.*?)m</", $split_times, $split_times_distances)`. I do have another (what I think is) a really great question about XML and its textContent parameter, I will post another comment here to notify you!

Comment: [This is my XML question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022059/xml-php-different-ouputs-of-attribute-inside-query-and-outside-query-but-with)